# How to create a point system in Prolog program without array

Tags: arrays, prolog

Hi i am trying to make a Prolog program in which  a user answers some question and I find the right game for him! I want to make a point system  where i keep the name and the points for each game when the answer suite with the characteristics of the game

for example :

```
sims3 :-
    simulationGame,
    rolePlayingGame.
dragonAgeII :-
    rolePlayingGame.

rolePlayingGamev :-
    test(do_you_like_play_games_with_structured_decision_and_chars_development).
simulationGame :-
    test(do_you_like_simulation_games).
```

but in Prolog i can't create an array what else should i do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to record the information in a list of pairs `[(gameA,7), (gameB,12)]` or in `assert`ed facts. The main question here would be how would you like to manipulate your data, and depending on your answer this or that data representation will be better suited.

Comment: when the user answer yes to the question i will save the name of the game and also i will have a variable p and i will increase p.and the game with biggest p will be the final result

Comment: OK, then both the list and the `assert`ed facts are fine.